# How do I set this messy placeholder in iPhone?

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

I make this form but when i check in my mobile i.e oppo it's look like this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jhkJ.png)

When I check this in iPhone it looks messy: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WejS3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can try following CSS to fix this issue:

```
line-height: 1;
```